# Ajax sending variables

Tags: php, ajax

I have trouble finding the issue, sending Id's from my database with ajax. I have this `$testjobids[$count].`, and it will contain the id received from my database. But how do I send it by image click to my other .php file?

```php
<?php
        if ($FlagStatus[$count] == ('YES')) {

            echo'<img class="Unflagging" src = "../Test/Images/Flag/FlagMarked.png">';
        } elseif($FlagStatus[$count] == ('NO')){
            echo'<img class="Flagging" src = "../Test/Images/Flag/FlagUnmarked.png">';
        }

echo'
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".Unflagging").click(function(){
              var FlagID = '.$testjobids[$count].'.val()              
                $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "echo.php",
                    data: { "FlagID":FlagID},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);    
                    }
                });
             });
        });
    </script>
    ';
?>
```

**echo.php**

```php
<?php
$receiver = $_POST['FlagID'];
echo $receiver;
?>
```

Comment: View the source to make sure your JS code is valid. Use your browser's DevTools to view the request/response being sent. What does `$testjobids[$count]` actually contain, just an id?

Comment: It's in a loop so every time the loops runs the id changes. But yeah just and ID

Comment: So `var FlagID = '.$testjobids[$count].'.val()` would become `var FlagID = 5.val()` in your rendered Javascript? That doesn't look correct. Try setting that to something like `var FlagID = "foo bar"` to test if your `echo.php` does receive something. Also temp change `echo $receiver;` to something like `echo 'bar baz';`to check if your Ajax call works

Comment: @kerbholz when i change `FlagID = '.$testjobids[$count].'.val()` to `FlagID = "foo bar"`, it alerts me with that text.

Comment: Ok then, everything seems to work except for `var FlagID = '.$testjobids[$count].'.val()`. Change that to just `var FlagID = '.$testjobids[$count].'`

Comment: Then it says, `<br/> <b> Notice:</b>: Undefined index: FlagID in <b>C:\xampp\......\echo.php</b> on line <b>2</b></br>`

Comment: I'm confused. So `$testjobids[$count]` is empty? Have you checked the source that everything is in place?

Comment: It prints the number if i just do a echo without ajax. I found somone doing somthing like this. `var altCheck = $(this).find('.Unflagging').attr('alt');` could somthing like that maybe work?

Comment: maybe `data: { "FlagID":FlagID},` **without the quotes** ... like `data: { FlagID:FlagID},`

Comment: @kerbholz found a solution for my question :) thanks for trying to help!